# Multiple UILabel at the same line in UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard

If there are multiple UILabels in one UIStoryboard, and they have the same centerY, which means they are at the same line. How can I use autolayout to let them fit in different screen? I hope these UILabels have same font size.

Comment: Are you saying you want to spread them out evenly in the same view (like a grid or list) or?

Comment: @brandonscript Yes, but the problem is that these labels, they have individual widths, so I don't know how to set constraints.

Comment: Check out [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/).

Comment: @brandonscript Thanks, that seems very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add constraints. There are a couple of ways to add constraints.

If you go to the storyboard you will see a rectangle in between 2 vertical lines. If you click the the view you want to add constraints too (Like the UIView you added) and click that rectangle box thing It gives you options to add constants to the left, right, top, bottom of the view. If you click on the dropdown menu it gives you a list of views around the view your adding constraints too so that you can add constraints relative to that view.

Another way to add constraints is clicking the triangle button in between 2 vertical lines and selecting the option "add missing constraints". Auto layout will then try and determine the best constraints to add automatically.

To delete or modify constraints you can click the "show size inspector" (looks like a ruler) and in the constraints section you should see some constraints if you have added any. You can click and delete them or edit them.

Another option is adding constraints programmatically (below is an example of adding constraints to an image view in a stack view in swift):

```
let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.stackView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -5)
let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.stackView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 5)

self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
self.stackView.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)
self.stackView.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
```

Comment: Cause when I set constraints on iPhone 6s, then at iPhone 5s it looks bad. So I want to find a way to make those UILabels looks nice in different screens, do you have any idea?

Comment: You can add it programmatically and resize or adjust constraints depending on screen size.

Comment: Thanks , I'll try to use programmatically way.